# Is summing a cosine similarity matrix a good way to determine overall similarity?

Tags: nlp, cosine-distance

I'm trying to similar research abstracts, so I'm using word embeddings to convert words into 1x768 vectors, so overall turning abstracts into embeddings with shape (#ofwords, 768). Cosine similarity between two abstracts returns a matrix (#ofwords1, #ofwords2), which I then sum up to get an overall score. What I'm wondering is if this summing up of all the values in a cosine similarity matrix is really a good way to determine overall similarity between two different texts? Is there a better, or less computationally expensive way to do this?

Comment: It's not very good because you're comparing every word with every other word, so your matrix is probably full of low scores which irrelevant and this is a potential bias. I'm not expert with embeddings but I think you could use document embeddings and calculate similarity between two document vectors. Otherwise you could try representing documents with traditional TFIDF vectors.

Answer (score 1):

A similar but more advanced approach would be [BERTScore](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09675). It also computes pairwise cosine similarity between (BERT) embeddings but uses greedy matching by only accounting for similarity between the closest tokens: [image]
*(based on Figure 1 from the BERTScore paper)*

However, it should be noted that BERTScore is designed to be used for paragraphs and not documents.

Another more traditional approach would be [doc2vec](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Equocle/paragraph_vector.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

A computationally simpler way is to compare documents is by calculating the cosine similarity of the average of the words embeddings for each document. The average of the word embeddings for a given document is one way to summarize the document.